# Decode base64 string in Swift

Tags: swift

I have following base64 encoded string:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjdEODU3RjE3RjMwQTBBNzY4OUQ4RTFDMTI0RjRFMzk1MEU2REIyQ0YiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJmWVZfRl9NS0NuYUoyT0hCSlBUamxRNXRzczgifQ
```

I easy decode it online, for example [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/base64/#.XUKf_y2B3Uo)

However when i try to decode it in swift i'm not succeed, i used:

```
func fromBase64() -> String? {
    guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else {
      return nil
    }

    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
  }
```

But i return nil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your string is missing the `=` padding characters at the end of a base64 output to make the string length divisible by 4. Try with

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjdEODU3RjE3RjMwQTBBNzY4OUQ4RTFDMTI0RjRFMzk1MEU2REIyQ0YiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJmWVZfRl9NS0NuYUoyT0hCSlBUamxRNXRzczgifQ==
```

Comment: `that usually occur at the end..` This is a bit misleading. Since his encoded string isn't divisible by 4, he needs 2 `==` to make it correct.

Comment: You're right, I've update my answer